# Ignore SIGINT signal in child process

Tags: c, signals

I am writing a simple program in which parent and child process are alternatively printing into a file. I have managed to do this using user defined signals. Now I want to handle the `SIGINT` signal. Once <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> is received the parent must send termination signal to child,the child should then should terminate and finally the parent should terminate.

My question is, in order to make this work properly I must catch the `SIGINT` signal ONLY from parent and IGNORE it from child. Is it right? If yes any hints on doing this?

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals

Comment: The above link no longer works.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Call:

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```

from the child process which will make the child process ignore the `SIGINT` signal. From [man signal](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal):

> If the disposition is set to SIG_IGN, then the signal is ignored.

Comment: Ok i know the SIG_IGN action,but i want ONLY the child to ignore that and when the parent catches the signal,terminate the child.

Comment: @SpyrosR, so only have the child call it?

Comment: Yes.I have set two handling functions,one for parent for catching the signal and sending SITERM signal to child and one for child for ignoring the signal but i cant make it work.If for example press ctrl-c while child is "working" it does call the child handle function but it does also call the parent handle function for the SIGINT signal.

Comment: Quick note: SIG_IGN does not work in gdb. gdb faults the program anyways.